# How can I display notifications in the background?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a Dart class that manages the display of my notifications from Firebase Messaging, I can display the notification when I'm in view of the application but when it's in the background I can't retrieve the content of the notification.

Here's what I tried with my Dart / Flutter code :

Here it's my class that handles the notification, and `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` works correction but not `FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundMessageHandler);`

```
Future<void> backgroundMessageHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  print('A background message was received: ${message.messageId}');
  // Mettez votre logique de traitement ici
}

class PushNotificationManager {
  final FirebaseMessaging _firebaseMessaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  Future<void> initNotifications() async {
    // Ask for permission if needed (iOS)
    NotificationSettings settings = await _firebaseMessaging.requestPermission(
      alert: true,
      badge: true,
      sound: true,
      provisional: true,
    );

    if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
      print("Notifications authorized");
      // Use the token for sending FCM messages
      String? token = await _firebaseMessaging.getToken();
      print("FirebaseMessaging token: $token");
    } else {
      print("Notifications not authorized");
    }

    // Enregistrez le gestionnaire de messages d'arrière-plan
    FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(backgroundMessageHandler);

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle the received notification when the app is in foreground
      print(
          "Received a message while in foreground: ${message.notification?.body}");
    });

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
      // Handle the notification caused by tapping the notification in the system tray
      print(
          "Tapped on a notification to open the app: ${message.notification?.body}");
    });

    // Handle notification tap when the app is terminated and not in the background
    RemoteMessage? initialMessage =
        await FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage();
    if (initialMessage != null) {
      print(
          "Tapped on a notification to open the app from terminated state: ${initialMessage.notification?.body}");
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, i have used OneSignal, the implementation was really simple.

He has a Flutter SDK to implement it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).